# Collections management with many derived elements

Tags: c#, design-patterns, collections

I've been told few days ago that using `is` is a code smell and anti-pattern.

I used it in an game to filter some elements of a collection (the inventory of the player).

---

**Classes structure**

The base class of an element of the collection is `Item` :

```
public abstract class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

From that class are derived 3 classes, `Potion`, `Armor` and `Weapon`

A potion is `IUsable`

```
public interface IUsable
{
    void Use(Character target);
}
```

And `IStackable`

```
public interface IStackable
{
    int Quantity { get; set; }
    int MaxQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

The class `Potion` is, in example, defined that way :

```
public class Potion : Item, IUsable, IStackable
{
    //Some properties and implementations of interfaces
}
```

The weapons and armors are `IEquipable`

```
public interface IEquipable
{
    void TakeOn(Character target);
    void TakeOff(Character target);
}
```

Here is a shortened example of `Armor`

```
public class Armor : Item, IEquipable
{
    //Some properties and implementations of interfaces
}
```

And one for `Weapon`

```
public class Weapon : Item, IEquipable
{
    //Some properties and implementations of interfaces
}
```

---

**Collection access**

Now, the part that smells, considering what was told to me :

To access some specific items in the collection, I'm using a generic method `SpecificInventoryItems<T>()`, which contains this part to get the expected `T` items :

```
foreach (Item item in player.Inventory)
{
    if (item is T)
    {
        string stack = "";
        if (item is IStackable)
        {
            var stackable = item as IStackable;
            stack = "(" + stackable.Quantity + "/" + stackable.MaxAmount + ") ";
        }
        options += "[" + i++ + "] - " + item.Name + " " + stack + ": " + item.Description;
        if (item is Armor)
            options += " " + ArmorDetail(item as Armor);
        else if (item is Weapon)
            options += " " + WeaponDetail(item as Weapon);
        options += "\n";
        items.Add(item as T); //items is List<T>
    }
}
```

What's wrong with it? How could (should) I redesign this structure ? I though using separates lists such as `List<IUsable>` and so on, instead of just a `List<Item> Inventory`

Another example, after displayed the specific elements of the inventory, the user can select an item, and depending of its type, the item will be either used or taken on :

```
switch (selected) //selected type is T
{
    case IEquipable eq:
        eq.TakeOn(player);
        break;

    case IUsable us:
        us.Use(player);
        //Manage the deletion of the IUsable if not IStackable, or IStackable and quantity = 0
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**Testable code**

The code below can be copied/pasted in VS as is, to be used for testing purposes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SOTests
{
    public abstract class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IUsable
    {
        void Use(Character target);
    }

    public class Character
    {
        public List<Item> Inventory { get; set; }

        public Character()
        {
            Inventory = new List<Item>
            {
                new Potion
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Lesser HP potion",
                    Description = "Heals 42 HP",
                    HPRestored = 42,
                    MaxQuantity = 20,
                    Quantity = 10
                },
                new Potion
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Greater HP potion",
                    Description = "Heals 100 HP",
                    HPRestored = 100,
                    MaxQuantity = 20,
                    Quantity = 10
                },
                new Armor
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Lesser Armor",
                    Description = "A basic armor",
                    Defense = 10
                },
                new Armor
                {
                    Id = 4,
                    Name = "Regular Armor",
                    Description = "An armor",
                    Defense = 25
                },
                new Armor
                {
                    Id = 5,
                    Name = "Superbe Armor",
                    Description = "A nice shiny armor",
                    Defense = 50
                },
                new Weapon
                {
                    Id = 42,
                    Name = "Lesser Sword",
                    Description = "A basic sword",
                    Attack = 50
                },
                new Weapon
                {
                    Id = 43,
                    Name = "Regular Sword",
                    Description = "A sword",
                    Attack = 75
                },
                new Weapon
                {
                    Id = 44,
                    Name = "Superbe Sword",
                    Description = "A nice shiny sword",
                    Attack = 100
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public class Potion : Item, IUsable, IStackable
    {
        public int HPRestored { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int MaxQuantity { get; set; }

        //This is not exactly how I implemented it, but it's sufficient for testing purpose
        public void Use(Character target)
        {
            --Quantity;
            Console.WriteLine("Used " + Name);
        }
    }

    public interface IStackable
    {
        int Quantity { get; set; }
        int MaxQuantity { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IEquipable
    {
        void TakeOn(Character target);
        void TakeOff(Character target);
    }

    public class Armor : Item, IEquipable
    {
        public int Defense { get; set; }
        //This is not how I implemented it, but it's sufficient for testing purpose
        public void TakeOn(Character target)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wearing armor : " + Name);
        }
        public void TakeOff(Character target) { }
    }

    public class Weapon : Item, IEquipable
    {
        public int Attack { get; set; }
        //This is not how I implemented it, but it's sufficient for testing purpose
        public void TakeOn(Character target)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wearing weapon : " + Name);
        }
        public void TakeOff(Character target) { }
    }

    public class AbsentFromInventory : Item
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static Character player = new Character();

        static string ArmorDetail(Armor armor)
        {
            return (armor.Name + " : " + armor.Description + " -> Defense : " + armor.Defense);
        }

        static string WeaponDetail(Weapon weapon)
        {
            return (weapon.Name + " : " + weapon.Description + " -> Attack : " + weapon.Attack);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Displays some elements of the inventory depending of its type
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="type">This is only for friendly display purpose</param>
        static void SpecificInventoryItems<T>(string type) where T : class
        {
            string error = "";
            string input;
            List<T> items;
            bool back = false;

            do
            {
                do
                {
                    items = null;
                    items = new List<T>();
                    string options = type + " :\n";
                    int i = 1;
                    if (player.Inventory.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (Item item in player.Inventory)
                        {
                            if (item is T)
                            {
                                string stack = "";
                                if (item is IStackable)
                                {
                                    var stackable = item as IStackable;
                                    stack = "(" + stackable.Quantity + "/" + stackable.MaxQuantity + ") ";
                                }
                                options += "[" + i++ + "] - " + item.Name + " " + stack + ": " + item.Description;
                                if (item is Armor)
                                    options += " " + ArmorDetail(item as Armor);
                                else if (item is Weapon)
                                    options += " " + WeaponDetail(item as Weapon);
                                options += "\n";
                                items.Add(item as T);
                            }
                        }

                        if (i > 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(options);
                            if (error != "")
                                Console.WriteLine(error);
                            Console.WriteLine("Please select an item or go [[B]ack]");
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("No " + type.ToLower() + " found. Please go [[B]ack]");
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("No item in inventory. Please go [[B]ack]");
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                    error = "";

                } while (!Regex.IsMatch(input, "^(([0-9]+)|(b(ack)?))$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

                if (int.TryParse(input, out int result))
                {
                    if (result > 0 && result <= items.Count)
                    {
                        var selected = items[--result];
                        switch (selected)
                        {
                            case IEquipable eq:
                                eq.TakeOn(player);
                                back = true;
                                break;

                            case IUsable us:
                                us.Use(player);
                                if (us is IStackable)
                                {
                                    var stackable = us as IStackable;
                                    if (stackable.Quantity <= 0)
                                        player.Inventory.Remove(stackable as Item);
                                }
                                else
                                    player.Inventory.Remove(us as Item);
                                back = true;
                                break;

                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        error = "Invalid number.";
                }
                else
                    back = true;
            } while (!back);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            do
            {
                SpecificInventoryItems<Potion>("Potion");
                SpecificInventoryItems<Weapon>("Weapon");
                SpecificInventoryItems<Armor>("Armor");
                SpecificInventoryItems<AbsentFromInventory>("Super item");
                Console.WriteLine("Again? Y/N");
            } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.N);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I find your question lacks a lot of details and context and that you should provide more code.

Comment: @t3chb0t sure, but there can be a lot of code that can be added. What part do you like to see? The whole function `SpecificInventoryItems<T>()` ?

Comment: Yes, for example. It's always easier if you can copy/paste the code into an IDE and don't have to create variables yourself like `items.Add(item as T); //items is List<T>`, this one isn't defined anywhere. It'd be great if you could make it copy/pasteable.

Comment: @t3chb0t I edited my question with testable code

Comment: One more thing, could you clarify which parts for the code are exactly as you implemented them and which ones are just for demonstration purposes. I see there are a couple of such commens already. How about the `SpecificInventoryItems`? I suppose this is what you want us to review, right? So how real is it?

Comment: `is` is NOT a code smell OR an anti-pattern. Whoever told you that needs to leave the industry.

Comment: @t3chb0t the `SpecificInventoryItems` is actually almost as it is in my project. I just removed 2 lines of codes that shows the player's stats which are irrevelant for the question. About the one that told me that `is` is anti-pattern and code smell, that was as comment about an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53651915/8398549) I wrote in SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### About 'is'

I see four different uses of `is` in your code:

1. `item is T`, for filtering on item type, such as weapons-only or potions-only.
2. `item is Armor` and `item is Weapon`, for creating type-specific effect descriptions.
3. `item is IStackable`, for descriptions and special inventory handling of stackable items.
4. `case IEquipable eq` and `case IUsable us`, for handling of equipment and consumption logic that applies to certain item 'categories' (both weapons and armors are equippable, only potions are consumable).

---

Number 1, selecting items of a specific type from a collection of different types (which is a very natural way to represent a player's inventory) seems fine. Note that this can be simplified by using Linq's `OfType<T>` extension method. An alternative such as using separate lists will likely introduce more problems than that they solve.

---

Number 2 is problematic. You can easily end up with several checks like these in multiple places, which makes updating description or other item-specific logic more difficult and error-prone than it needs to be. A better solution is to add a virtual `EffectsDescription` property to `Item`, so each item type can generate its own effects description, using actual effect values. Adding a new item type no longer requires changes in various other parts of the code, because type-specific description logic is kept in a single place, the item class itself.

---

Number 3, stackable item handling, looks ok at first sight, but it's not very flexible. A class either implements an interface or it does not, so each item type is either stackable or it's not. A two-handed broadsword isn't stackable, but what about a set of throwing knives? The current design does not allow for special cases like that. I would use a data-driven approach here instead of encoding this in C#'s type system. The easiest solution would be to make all items stackable, with a max stack size of 1 for unstackable items.

---

Number 4, equippable and consumable item handling, can sometimes be useful, but in this case I think it indicates a suboptimal design choice. A call like `SpecificInventoryItems<Weapon>` is intended to let the player select a weapon, but because `SpecificInventoryItems` is a generic method it has to resort to type-checks to determine how to use the selected item - something that could easily (and unambiguously) have been decided by the caller. I would split this up into a generic `SelectItem<T>` method and several type-specific methods such as `EquipWeapon`.

---

#### Other notes

- Pattern matching isn't limited to `switch` statements: `if (item is Armor) ...item as Armor` can be rewritten as `if (item is Armor armor) ...armor`. That also reduces the number of type checks to one.
- `SpecificInventoryItems` is doing too many things. Splitting it up into smaller functions that each perform a single task not only makes the code easier to understand, it also enables you to reuse functionality in different contexts.
- `Item.Description` is used inconsistently: potions use it to describe their effects, but weapons and armor do not. Note how potion descriptions can easily become incorrect if you change the value of `HPRestored` but forget to update `Description` accordingly.
- The `T : class` constraint does not prevent unrelated interfaces and types. A top-level `IItem` interface that is implemented by both `Item` and the various equippable/usable interfaces allows for a more specific constraint, which makes the intent of the method more clear. Renaming `T` to `TItem` would also help.
- If you're using `options` the way you do to reduce the number of `Console.WriteLine` calls, and if that's because of a concern for performance, then you should know that using a `StringBuilder` is more efficient than concatenating lots of strings. Not that I'm expecting performance problems here, but just in case you didn't know.
- All `Item` properties have public setters. This allows any code to modify them, with the risk of putting an item in an invalid state, with the result that a modification in one part of the program can cause another unrelated part to break.

---

#### Alternative implementation

Here's what the code could look like after applying some of the above suggestions:

```
// Top-level item-specific methods:
static void EquipWeapon(Character player)
{
    var selectedWeapon = AskUserToSelectItem<Weapon>(player, "weapon");
    if (selectedWeapon == null)
        return;

    // NOTE: Unequipping current weapon left out.
    selectedWeapon.TakeOn(player);
    Console.WriteLine($"{selectedWeapon.Name} has been equipped.");
}

static void EquipArmor(Character player)
{
    var selectedArmor = AskUserToSelectItem<Weapon>(player, "armor");
    if (selectedArmor == null)
        return;

    // NOTE: Unequipping current armor left out.
    selectedArmor.TakeOn(player);
    Console.WriteLine($"{selectedArmor.Name} has been equipped.");
}

static void ConsumeUsableItem(Character player)
{
    var selectedUsableItem = AskUserToSelectItem<IUsable>(player, "consumable");
    if (selectedUsableItem == null)
        return;

    RemoveFromInventory(player, selectedUsableItem, 1);
    selectedUsableItem.Use(player);
    Console.WriteLine($"{selectedUsableItem.Name} has been consumed.");
}

// Displays all items of the specified type.
// Returns the selected item, or null if no item was selected.
static TItem AskUserToSelectItem<TItem>(Character player, string itemDisplayName) where TItem : IItem
{
    var items = player.Inventory.OfType<TItem>().ToArray();
    if (items.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Your inventory contains no {itemDisplayName}.");
        return default;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{itemDisplayName}:");
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] - {FullItemDescription(items[i])}");
    }
    var selectedIndex = AskUserForIntegerInRange($"Please select an item or go [[B]ack]:", 0, items.Length - 1);
    return selectedIndex.HasValue ? items[selectedIndex.Value] : default;
}

static void RemoveFromInventory(Character player, IItem item, int quantity)
{
    // NOTE: Ownership and quantity sanity check left out for brevity's sake:
    if (item.Quantity > quantity)
        item.Quantity -= quantity;
    else
        player.Inventory.Remove(item);
}

static string FullItemDescription(IItem item)
{
    var description = new StringBuilder();
    description.Append(item.Name);

    if (item.StackSize > 1)
        description.Append($" ({item.Quantity}/{item.StackSize})");

    description.Append($": {item.Description} -> {item.EffectsDescription}");
    return description.ToString();
}

// Asks the user to enter a number within the given range.
// Returns null if the user entered 'b' or 'back'.
static int? AskUserForIntegerInRange(string prompt, int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        var input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        if (input == "b" || input == "back")
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (int.TryParse(input, out var index))
        {
            if (index >= minValue && index <= maxValue)
                return index;

            Console.WriteLine($"Please enter a number between {minValue} and {maxValue}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number, or 'b' or 'back'.");
        }
    }
}
```

With the following changes to the `Item` class hierarchy (not including everything, but the rest should be obvious):

```
public interface IItem
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    string EffectsDescription { get; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
    int StackSize { get; }
}

public abstract class Item : IItem
{
    ...
    public virtual string EffectsDescription { get; }
}

public interface IEquippable : IItem { ... }

public class Weapon : Item, IEquippable
{
    ...
    public override string EffectsDescription => $"Attack: {Attack}";
}
```

Perhaps not all of these changes will make sense for what you have in mind with your game, but I hope you'll find some of this useful.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, I'll study it carefully. As you mentionned, there's some parts I can't use, in example, the case 2. I'm developping the game using a 3-tiers architecture and I don't want to use only strings for the details of an `Item` (later, I plan to give up the console and use something more visual, like Unity 3D)

Comment: That makes sense - normally you wouldn't store display-strings at this level, you'd provide information that can be translated or visualized by the UI layer. I'd probably add an `Effect` property to `IItem`, with an effect-type enum (damage/armor/healing/etc.) and a value. That could be extended to an `Effects` array if items can have multiple effects, or the value could be replaced by a range, for weapons with randomized damage, and so on.

Comment: This is already the case, I have an `Status` base class that is derived for `Buff` (that is used for debuff too) `OverTime` (derived to `Dot` - Damage Over Time - and planned to `Hot` - Healing Over Time). This can be used in buff/debuff/poison potions and in skills. This is actually a 5000 lines project available on GitHub :)

Comment: Armors have 2 main attributes, the `Defense` and the type (which is an enum). If you have a breastplate (chest armor) having 3 in `Defense` of type Plate. You've been hit on the chest by an attack dealing 10 damage. Your armor has 3 in defense, and the damages are reduced to 7. The plate type reduce the damage by 40%, the damage is 4.2 (rounded to 4). Depending of the type of the weapon (pierce, blunt or slash), the damage are increased or decreased